# Need help configuring apache on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apache2

I successfully installed the Apache webserver on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop.

Now I need to know how to change the configuration file(s) so that I can place my CGI scripts (which will be in Perl).

From my time using Apache2.4 under Windows 10, it was easy. I just made needed changes to the `httpd.conf` file. Under this configuration, things are very different so I am not sure how to make the needed changes. I looked at the `apache2.conf` file and the declaration for the `ServerRoot` directive was commented out.

While I was reading up on how to install apache I saw a statement which read "Documentation for the web server itself can be found by accessing the "manual" if the apache2-doc package was installed on this server". I ran an `apt` command and installed the `apache2-doc` package, but how do I use it?

I need to know how to change the configuration files so that I can define the location of the directory containing all my Perl CGI scripts.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu (and in other distros), Apache configuration is organized in multiple files for easier maintenance and upgrading. You would find:

- `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`: Main config file for global configuration, usually discourage to modify this file.
- `/etc/apache2/conf-available/`: Directory where you can add different configurations files to keep things well organized.
- `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/`: Directory that contains symlinks from `/etc/apache2/conf-available` directory. Every file or symlink in this directory is automatically included by `apache2.conf`.
- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`: Directory to keep your sites configuration files. If you have multiple websites hosted on your Apache, you can have multiple files here, one for each one. Otherwise, you can just use the `000-default.conf` file that already exists there.
- `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`: Directory that contains symlinks from `/etc/apache2/sites-available` directory. Every file or symlink in this directory is automatically included by `apache2.conf`.
- `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`: Directory where all the available Apache modules are stored and their configuration files.
- `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`: Directory that contains symlinks from `/etc/apache2/mods-available` directory. Every file or symlink in this directory is automatically included by `apache2.conf`.

There are few commands that makes creating and deleting these symlinks from `*-available` to `*-enabled` a bit easier, like:

- `a2ensite`: Enables a site by creating the symlink to `sites-enabled`.
- `a2dissite`: Disables a site by deleting the symlink from `sites-enabled`.
- `a2enmod`:  Enables a module by creating the symlink to `mods-enabled`.
- `a2dismod`: Disables a module by deleting the symlink from `mods-enabled`.
- `a2enconf`:  Enables a config by creating the symlink to `conf-enabled`.
- `a2disconf`: Disables a config by deleting the symlink from `conf-enabled`.

Most likely, you would just need to modify the file `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` with your site config if your requirements are simple. For more complex scenarios, is recommended to have your own site config.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I modified the sites-enabled/000-default.conf file by removing the '#' from the start of the "Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf" line. I then created the /usr/lib/cgi-bin directory. I next put a small Perl CGI script named "printenv.cgi" under /usr/lib/cgi-bin. I then restarted the apache2 server. When I attempted to run my newly created CGI script gy visiting  http://localhost:80/cgi-bin/printenv.cgi all that happened was I received a "404 Not Found" error. I looked at the apache logfile and it provided no further info.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: You probably need to enable CGI module. To do this, you have to run `a2enmod cgi`, this will create a symlink from directory `/etc/apache2/mods-available/` to `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`, where the enabled modules are. Then, just restart Apache and it should work.

Comment: Updated my answer with the modules info and the Apache helper commands.

Comment: that seems to have done the trick. thank you very much for your help.